# $\int_0^1\frac{(f(x)-1)^2 -4x^2}{x^{3.5}}\,dx$ exists. Calculate $f(0)$ and $f'(0)$

Tags: continuity, improper-integrals

I've tried somehow using Taylor to try and figure this one out.

Unfortunately, I couldn't seem to get a solid answer.
Thank you very much for your help!

Let f be a continuos function,
$$f:R\rightarrow R$$
$$f(x), \  f'(x)  \ , \ f''(x) \ \text{are continuous} $$

and let the integral
$$\int_0^1\frac{(f(x)-1)^2 -4x^2}{x^{3.5}}\,dx \space \text{exist and be finite}$$

Find the value of 
$$f(0)\ \text{and}\ |f'(0)|$$

Comment: Do not use displaystyle in titles. Please add your thoughts.

Comment: sorry, the only reason ive done that is because my last post was edited by someone and he changed it to displaystyle.

Comment: Integral $\int g$ to exist it is necessary that $g$ is finite everywhere. Only possible if$ f(x) = 1 + 4x^2 + kx^n$ which means f(0) = 1 and f'(0) = 0

Comment: You're wrong on two counts, alekhine. You don't need the function to be bounded at the origin. And you didn't expand correctly either. See my answer.

Comment: @eyal: Which post was that?

Comment: @Did it was this one http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389527/int-01-fracfxxp-exists-and-finite-implies-f0-0
and sorry for the delayed answer. thank you.

Comment: @eyal Nobody introduced displaystyle in your other post.

Comment: @Did i think i dont understand what do you mean by displaystyle ? 
i thought u ment that i inserted lyx code in the headline.. 
what did u mean?

Comment: LaTeX has two styles for maths, textstyle (encoded by `$...$`) and displaystyle (often encoded by `$$...$$`). The latter is made for displayed maths, the former for intext maths. One should restrict to textstyle in titles of posts on MSE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a=f(0)-1, b=f'(0)$. Then continuity of the second derivative gives $f(x)= 1+a+ bx+O(x^2)$ and hence the integrand is
$$\frac{(a+bx+O(x^2))^2-4x^2}{x^{3.5}} = \frac{a^2+2abx+(b^2+a\times\cdots-4)x^2+O(x^3)}{x^{3.5}}$$
A function like $x^c$ is integrable at the origin only if $c>-1$ (check) and hence the first term in the numerator which may be nonzero is the cubic term.

You should be able to figure out what $a,|b|$ are now.

Comment: can u please explaine the how why the equaition or the LHS and RHS are equal? i cant seem to understand how u got there

Comment: $(a+b+c)^2= a^2+ 2ab + (b^2+2ac) +(2bc+ c^2)$ right? That's just expanding a square out and grouping the terms together. That's all I did, except that I noticed that we don't care about terns that have $x^3$ or higher in them.

Comment: @eyal Knowing the answer is helpful I guess :P, you will find $ f(0) = 1 $ and $ |f'(0)| = 2 $, you may go along the given solution.

Comment: @smiley06 I don't leave bits out from spite, y'know! The idea is to get people over the stumbling blocks, rather than doing everything for them; it's more helpful in the long run P:

Comment: @Sharkos Ok i can show that $f(0) = 1 $
but im still not sure how to show that $|f'(0)=2| $
or maybe im doing something wrong? any hints? guidence?
thank you!

Comment: What can the coefficient of $x^2$ in my numerator be? Now since $a=0$ you have an equation involving $b$. But $b=f'(0)$...